# Space between horizontal an vertical border in table is ignored

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get a space of ~20 px between the red `tr` border and the blue border of the  `table` but only in the `tbody` **not** it in the `thead`.
I tried to use padding on the tr but this does not work.

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  border: 3px solid blue;
   border-collapse: collapse;
}

thead {
  background-color: green;
}
tr {
 height:50px;
}

tr {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>FooHead</td>
      <td>BarHead</td>
      <td>BazHead</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Foo</td>
      <td>Bar</td>
      <td>Baz</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Foo</td>
      <td>Bar</td>
      <td>Baz</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Foo</td>
      <td>Bar</td>
      <td>Baz</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Put it in a div - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/mKgPmE and pad *that*.

Comment: Hehe I didn't think you were gonna give that solution. This is not gonna work for me because the border of the tr in the table head should connect to the blue line.

Answer (score 1):

One trick you can use is to scale the `tr`s in the `tbody` horizontally, so that they no longer are as wide as the table.
If you do that, you'll have to adjust some of the other CSS as well; for instance you can no longer use `border-collapse: collapse`, since this makes the horizontal lines connect to the vertical.

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  border: 3px solid blue;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

thead {
  background-color: green;
}

tr {
  height: 50px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
}

tbody tr {
  transform: scaleX(.95);
}

tbody td {
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>FooHead</td>
      <td>BarHead</td>
      <td>BazHead</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Foo</td>
      <td>Bar</td>
      <td>Baz</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Foo</td>
      <td>Bar</td>
      <td>Baz</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Foo</td>
      <td>Bar</td>
      <td>Baz</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try to use `:after` of `<td>` selector to display the bottom line instead of using `<tr>` border
But this would be a bit tricky.

However, with this trick, you can apply a padding-left to your first column (the bottom line will follow).. And you can change the width of the last `td:after` with a `calc(100 - 20px)`

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  border: 3px solid blue;
   border-collapse: collapse;
}

thead {
  background-color: green;
}
tr {
 height:50px;
}

tr {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
tbody td {
  position: relative;
}
tbody td:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: red;
  bottom: 0;
}
tbody tr:last-of-type td:after {
  display: none;
}
td:first-of-type {
  padding-left: 20px;
}

tbody td:last-of-type:after {
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>FooHead</td>
      <td>BarHead</td>
      <td>BazHead</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Foo</td>
      <td>Bar</td>
      <td>Baz</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Foo</td>
      <td>Bar</td>
      <td>Baz</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Foo</td>
      <td>Bar</td>
      <td>Baz</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Note that I targeted only td of the tbody.. This can be extanded to the header to display also the red line in there, by just removing `tbody` prefix in the CSS